# Debugging Java application running in linux through vnc server, from Netbeans installed in Windows

Tags: debugging, netbeans, vnc

I have my java application in linux system which I remotely access through VNC server.
On my local desktop(windows) I have netbeans IDE installed.

I want to debug the application which I access using vnc server through Netbeans installed on my windows.
Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks,
Rohit